# jquery popup not opening properly - seems stuck in div?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm working on a website: http://www.ourbridalsongs.com and am trying to implement a hover type
menu when clicking on the arrows next to the logo.

For some reason - rather than opening fully - the menu seems to get stuck and doesn't expand fully.

I'm pretty sure this is a CSS error - if anyone could take a look using Firebug - I'd much appreciate it - Thank-you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah you mean Themeforest like. Okay

You have to change in header.css

```
ul.topnav li {
    float: left;
    margin:0 0 0 10px;
    position: relative; /*--Declare X and Y axis base--*/
}
```

to

```
ul.topnav li {
    float: left;
    margin:0 0 0 10px;
    position: relative; /*--Declare X and Y axis base--*/
    overflow: visible;
}
```

I've set the overflow to visible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the subnav UL to be larger than the logo image, you'll need to move it out of header_new. I would move it into `<div id="header_bar">`.

If you move it like this, you may also have to adjust the selector you are using to find it in your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is easy: you have `overflow: hidden` applied to the parent `li` of the pop up.

From line 6 of comment.css:

```
li {
  list-style: none outside none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

That means this style is applied to *all* `li`s on the page.

What you'd probably want is to give the selector a bit more specificity so that it won't select the wrong element. Given that its obvious you only want the styles in that CSS file to be applied to comments, I'd add an additional `#comments` to each of the selectors in that stylesheet so that they won't be unintentionally applied to other elements.